# Error en consulta PHP y MySQL Notice: Undefined index

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

me sale el siguiente error al ejecutar
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prins\usuarios.php on line 16
Notice: Undefined index: username in C:\xampp\htdocs\Prins\usuarios.php on line 17
Error

Este es el codigo

```
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$con = new conexion();

if(isset($_POST['ingresar'])){

    if(!isset($_POST["username"]) && !isset($_POST["password"]) ){
        echo "error";
    }else{
        $usuario = $_POST['username'];
        $clave = $_POST['password'];
   
    $resultado = mysqli_query($con->conectar(),"SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE username='$usuario' and password = '$clave'");
    
        while($consulta = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){
            echo $consulta['username'];
            if($consulta['username'] == $usuario && $consulta['password'] == $clave){
                echo "<script>
                location.href='pagina.php';
                </script>";
            }else{
                echo "Error";
            } 
        }
    }
}
```

Conexion

```
<?php
class conexion
{
    private $__link;

    public function conectar()
    {
        $this->link = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'crudsalas');
        if ($this->link->connect_errno) {
            echo "Falló la conexión a MySQL: (" . $this->link->connect_errno . ") " . $this->link->connect_error;
        }
        return $this->link;
    }
}
```

las lineas de error las marca en

```
16 echo $consulta['username'];
17 if($consulta['username'] == $usuario && $consulta['password'] == $clave)
```

Comment: y cual es la linea 16 y 17???

Comment: ha y cambia esto `if(!isset($_POST["username"]) && !isset($_POST["password"]) ){` por `if(!isset($_POST["username"]) || !isset($_POST["password"]) ){`

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 Te manco las lineas al final del escrito, verifica.

Comment: ok sabes hacer debug???

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 no

Comment: leete esto: https://www.php.net/manual/es/debugger.php

Comment: y esto otro: https://stackify.com/php-debugging-guide/

Comment: el problema que tienes es muy simple; si yo lo resuelvo tu no aprenderías nada ... aquí el problema esta en que debes aprender a hacer debug de forma individual ...

Comment: el error que re sale indica que la consulta devuelta de la base de datos no trae el índice que estas iterando.. puede ser por que el query esta mal hecho o por que no existen los registros que estas filtrando... de tal manera el índice no existe y eso provoca el error ...

Comment: Gracias @ArcanisGK507 me ha servido de mucho.

Comment: En cualquier caso... no has mostrado la definición de la tabla de usuarios en la Base de Datos.. Imagínate que la columna se llama `usuario` y no `username`. Podría ser por algo así, por ejemplo